# What is the right way to create ViewModels with Repository pattern

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, repository

I am learning to use ASP.NET MVC with the Repository pattern. 
I have a list of Users and a list of Roles. Users contain a RoleId, and Roles contain a RoleName and Id. I want to return a list of UsersWithRoles and put it in a ViewModel that has a UserName and a RoleName. What is the right way to proceed. 
I am thinking of: 
   1) Get the list of Names and Roles and fill the ViewModel from the controller(foreach)
   2) Join the Roles and Names in the Repository and return them as an Entity to the Controller, where I fill the ViewModel
   3) Join the Roles and Names in the Repository and return as a ViewModel directly

Comment: @derloopkat I want to list all users, with their roles

Answer (score 0):

u can done this by get user records using LINQ and using that user info u can again get record of role using LINQ. at the end u can add in custom model and that model u can send to respected view.

**In Controller**

Find Specific record and store common field (Primary Data) to the local variable

```
var Users = _Entity.UserInfoTable.Where(p => p.UserCode.Equals(UserID)).FirstOrDefault();
string strUserID = Users.UserID
```

strUserID hold the UserID

now using local variable get the role data specific to that user

```
var UserRole = _Entity.UserRoleTable.Where(p => p.UserCode.Equals(strUserID)).FirstOrDefault()
```

Final step : add UserRole data to the Custom/View model/Repo

```
CustomeModel cm = new CustomeModel();
cm.UserID  = UserRole.UserID;
cm.RoleID = UserRole.RoleID;
cm.RoleName = UserRole.RoleName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var usersWithRoles = (from u in Users
                         join r in Roles on r.Id equals u.RoleId
                         select new UserWithRoles{
                                UserName = u.UserName,
                                RoleName = r.RoleName

                        }).ToList();
```